# Circle Clicking game simple python

Tags: python, if-statement, graphics

Okay so my objective is to create a game.

While the users score is less than 10 (it is initially set to 0), I want when clicked in a inscribed square around the circle to have a random number between 0 and 5 added to the score.

Right now when I am clicking for some reason new circles are being drawn. If it is clicked in the circle I want that circle to be undrawn and a and a new circle to be drawn in a random location.

```
from graphics import *

import random

def main():
    win= GraphWin("lab12",500,500)
    score=0
    while score < 10:
        x=random.randint(0,450)
        y=random.randint(0,450)
        centa=Point(x,y)
        c=Circle(centa,50)
        c.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
        c.draw(win)
        mouseClick2=win.getMouse()
        if mouseClick2.y >= y-50 and mouseClick2.y <= y +50 and mouseClick2.x >= x-50 and mouseClick2.x <= x+50:
            score=score + random.randint(0,5)
            c.undraw()
            x=random.randint(0,450)
            y=random.randint(0,450)
            centa=Point(x,y)
            c=Circle(centa,50)
            c.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
            c.draw(win)

        else:
            score=score+0
    print "you won"
    print "your final score is, " 


main()
```

Comment: Just so you know, `else: score=score+0` does nothing.

Comment: yeah i should take that out but still...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about instead of trying to clear the circle you simple translate and move the coordinates?

I did so with the following

```
def draw_circle(win, c=None):
    x=random.randint(0,450)
    y=random.randint(0,450)

    if c is None:
        centa=Point(x,y)
        c = Circle(centa,50)
        c.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
        c.draw(win)
    else:
        p1 = c.p1
        x_dif = (p1.x - x) * -1
        y_dif = (p1.y - y) * -1
        c.move(x_dif, y_dif)
    return (c, x, y)
```

The basic translation algo is `newX = (x1-x2) * -1` and `newY = (y1-y2) * -1`.  we swap the sign because a negative value indicates that the new x coordinate is greater than the old coordinate and should instead be moved right (not left, which is indicated by the move).

This changes your main loop to the following:

```
def main():
    win= GraphWin("lab12",500,500)
    score=0
    c,x,y = draw_circle(win)
    while score < 10:
        mouseClick2=win.getMouse()
        if mouseClick2.y >= y-50 and mouseClick2.y <= y +50 and mouseClick2.x >= x-50 and mouseClick2.x <= x+50:
            score=score + random.randint(0,5)
        c,x,y = draw_circle(win, c)

    print "you won"
    print "your final score is, {0}".format(score)
```

Remember that in python you can **`unpack`** a tuple/array/generator onto a set of variables granted your number of variables matches the size of said tuple/array/generator.

e.g.

```
x,y,z = 5,10,20  # works
x,y = 5,10,20    # does not work
x,y,z = 5,10     # does not work
```

Oh and i added your score to the print statement!